# Problem using OptionValue with functions defined by SubValues, and the use of Options for function dispatch

Tags: options

I have a function that looks like:

```
(a : pump[_, __])["curve QH", opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Plot[x, {x, 0, 2}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"}, 
  Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot]]]
```

This code allows me to substitute the option of `Plot`, with whatever I may want (where `pump` acts like a very simple object).

Now suppose I want to use an option to define if a `Plot` or a `Table` should be outputed.

I imagined something like this:

```
(a : pump[_, __])["curve QH", opts : OptionsPattern["type" -> "plot"]] :=
 Which[
  OptionValue["type"] == "plot",
  Plot[x, {x, 0, 2}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"}, 
   Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot]]]],
  OptionValue["type"] == "table",
  Table[x, {x, 0, 2, 0.1}]
  ]
```

but it doesn't work.

What is the best strategy to use Options with this kind of definition?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two problems I see with this code. The first one, and the one which gives you immediate problem you reported, is that, as it looks, short (magical) form of `OptionValue` does not work with `SubValues` - based definitions. So, you should replace

```
OptionValue["type"]
```

with

```
OptionValue[{opts}, "type"]
```

Or, if you wish to associate the option with `pump` directly and use it within the `SubValue`, you need to use

```
OptionValue[pump, {opts}, "type"]
```

instead.

The second, "conceptual" problem, is that you are really trying to use options for function dispatch, but in doing this your way, you give up the powerful rule-based function dispatch mechanism that is naturally available in mma. This is what I would do instead:

```
ClearAll[pump, dispatch];
(a : pump[_, __])["curve QH", opts : OptionsPattern["type" -> "plot"]] :=
    dispatch[pump, OptionValue[{opts}, "type"]][a, "curve QH", opts];

dispatch[pump, "plot"][_, _, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
   Plot[x, {x, 0, 2}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"}, 
      Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot]]]];

dispatch[pump, "table"][_, _, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
   Table[x, {x, 0, 2, 0.1}]
```

I delegated the dispatch to a new (extra) symbol `dispatch`, introduced specifically for this purpose. This looks cleaner and more extensible to me than using `Which` statement.

**EDIT**

Addressing the issue raised in comments: note that, as another manifestation of `OptionValue` - `OptionsPattern` magic being lost for `SubValues`- based functions, the above solution, as written, will not provide the intended default behavior, when the `"type"` option is not explicitly given. To make that work, one can do:

```
(a : pump[_, __])["curve QH", opts : OptionsPattern["type" -> "plot"]] :=
    dispatch[
       pump, 
       OptionValue[{opts,"type" -> "plot"}, "type"]
    ][a, "curve QH", opts];
```

adding the default option explicitly in `OptionValue`.

Comment: Everything works fine, with the exception that "type" default value ("plot") isn't being considered. If I set no option, it ends up calling dispatch[pump, "type"] (which isn't defined)

Comment: @P.Fonseca It looks like this is another manifestation of `OptionValue` - `OptionsPattern` having lost some of their magic properties for `SubValues`. Just change `OptionValue[{opts}, "type"]` to `OptionValue[{opts,"type" -> "plot"}, "type"]` and it should work.

Comment: Your last suggestion works. Thank you. When you can, please update your answer so that both "solutions" are shown: the one that should work if the magic was fully integrated (and that will, one day, eventually work...), and the one with your work around from your comment. Than you again...

Comment: @P.Fonseca  Done.

Comment: If you wish to associate the set of options with `pump`, and access them via its `SubValues`, then you need to use `OptionValue[pump, {opts}, optName]`, instead.

Comment: @rcollyer That's a good point. Care to edit my answer and include it, or do you want me to do this?

Comment: Added it. Check it for grammar, wording, etc., if you would.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks, perfect! Besides, me checking your edit for grammar and wording does not make much sense, I am not even a native speaker (and the number of typos and other language blunders I notice in my comments and posts upon reading them a while after they were posted is just ridiculous - and I can imagine how many more I just never notice ) :)

Comment: The irony of my comment did not elude me. But, I find having another person check it is helpful.